# WatchOS and iOS new .accessoryInline Widget does not display everything

Tags: ios, watchos, widgetkit

I'm trying to made an WatchOS extension with the new type `.accessoryInline`But I don"t understand why I cannot have more than one stack in the main horizontal stack.

See the invisible stack in the following commented code and in the WatchOS simulator

[image]

```
struct WidgetInlineView : View {
    var entry: BurnoutTimelineEntry
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 5) {
            HStack {
                Image("widgetWork")
                Text(entry.exchange.todayWork.durationString)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Image("widgetPause")
                Text(entry.exchange.todayPause.durationString)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WidgetInline: Widget {
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: "MyKind", provider: BurnoutTimelineProvider()) { entry in
            WidgetInlineView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
        .supportedFamilies([.accessoryInline])
    }
}

struct WidgetInline_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WidgetInlineView(entry: BurnoutTimelineEntry(date: Date()))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .accessoryInline))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inline widgets only display the *first* text item and the *first* image. Everything else is ignored and they ignore any styling, too. And to top it off, it's very picky about the image size (I have not found the exact limits yet): if your image is too large it won't get rendered, even if you marked it as resizable.

Comment: I found that 26 x 26 images are rendered correctly

Answer (score 1):

I come to the same conclusion as answered by [@DarkDust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400056/darkdust)

Regarding text, my work around is to use text concatenation. something like this...

```
Text("Hello") + Text("\(name) ") + Text(Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle.fill"))
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But I wasn’t able to use image coming from assets catalog. Only system images seems to work.